# Prediction for time-series data gives constant values

Tags: time-series, python, predictive-models, autoregressive, statsmodels

I tried generating an AR process and checked whether it is predictable. After generating 5000 values of AR process, I put the first 4000 values as in-sample in *statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order()* and predict the rest of 1000 values.
Although it predicts in-sample accurately, out-of-sample prediction gets constant and considerably different from the true values.

I wonder why it happened and could someone me give any advice?
[image]

My code is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels as sm
import statsmodels.api as smp
%matplotlib inline


#----- generate AR process sample
np.random.seed(12345)
arparams = np.array([0.9])
maparams = np.array([0])
ar = np.r_[1, -arparams] # add zero-lag and negate
ma = np.r_[1, maparams] # add zero-lag
y = smp.tsa.arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, 5000)

#----- fit in-sample and predict out-of-sample
estimated_model = sm.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order(y[:4000], maxlag=5, ic='aic', glob=True)
res = estimated_model.model.fit()
print(res.summary()) # checked if my AR process is correct

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=False)
ax.set_title("Pred")
ax.plot(y, label='truth')
ax.plot(res.predict(0,5000,), label='pred')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior for any ARIMA model. These models quickly converge to flat lines (if there is no differencing), or to the appropriate linear trend (if the order of differencing is 1), or to higher trends (for higher order differencing, which should rarely be used).

Note that the initial forecasts are not flat, and it only looks flat because you are forecasting a long way out:

```
res.predict(0,10,)
array([        nan,         nan,         nan, -0.19471936, -0.6925775 ,
        1.06673156,  2.27563109,  2.14843756,  2.14919931,  2.6125645 ,
        3.46204872])
```

You have a very simple AR(3) model with a nonzero intercept and should be able to calculate the forecasts by hand.

We have [many earlier posts on flat ARIMA forecasts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5barima%5d%20flat%20forecast), take a look at those. As to why your predictions vary much less than your history, [the two links here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352) should be helpful.

Comment: Good question! That time series has strong seasonal dynamics (it's housing starts), which are captured in the first model by very high lag orders (anything around 12 for monthly data *always* suggests seasonality, which should be captured by SARIMA), and in the second model by "seasonal dummies" (whatever that is - SARIMA works not through dummies, but through seasonal differencing). The is just more (seasonal) signal here. Which is presumably why this series was chosen for illustration, it looks much more "sophisticated" than typical time series with fast decay in the forecast.

Comment: Thanks again, Stephan. I deleted my response by mistake, however I understand your point.